# Android image is elongated horizontally

Tags: android

I have to display an image which has to be half screen size.

[image]

The main Linear Layout of this  activity has 3 linear layouts.

In first linear layout is **ImageView** which height size has to be 1/2 size of the screen. This image is parsed from html tag and loaded to ImageView with Picasso.
The picture is elongated, and I want it to be normal.

The second and third layout has to to be remaining 1/2 size of the screen.

You can see it from the image below:

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below solution

In your XML file change to ImageView Like that

```
    <com.nitin.widgets.DynamicImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsimageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
```

Here is the full code snippiest for avoid thin gaps along the left/right edges

DynamicImageView.java

```
  package com.nitin.widgets;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {
      public DynamicImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)   
          {
           super(context, attrs);
          }
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
        //avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
 }
}
```

I will suggest to try to us this solution. It will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **scaleType** option to **CenterCrop** , this option show image in better scale .

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this layout.Set orientation of the child linearlayout as per your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```